# Validation by Using CONCAT in COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to concatenate the value of two columns in the current sheet and then result should be compared with the concatenation of two column value in another sheet.

e.g - The entered value in Column W and X in current sheet after concatenation should be compared with the existing value in column Y and column Z(after concat) of another sheet.

I have tried using the formula **COUNTIF(Sheet2!CONCAT($W$2,$X$2:$Y$2,$Z$2),A2)>0** and some different alteration in this but it seems COUNTIF has range and criteria as argument and this is string which is causing error.

Comment: You can not use concat that way.  Can you mock up some data that shows what you are trying and expected output?

Comment: @Scott Craner , I have an excel comprise of two sheet : Sheet1 and Sheet2

**Sheet 1** 

ColumnA  ColumnB   fieldCombination

123             XYZ           123XYZ

This field combination I am trying to validate in sheet 2 of same excel 

**Sheet 2**

ColumnC  Column D     fieldCombination
123             XYZ               123XYZ              

_Without fieldCombination(single column value) I can able to validate using **=COUNTIF(Sheet2!C:D,E2)>0** where E refers to the column in Sheet 1 where I want to apply the validation_. But I want to validate with `fieldCombination`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare, a simple '=' will do.

Concatenation can be done using '&'.

in current sheet:

```
=W1&X1=Sheet2!Y1&Sheet2!Z1
```

will return TRUE if both concatenations are equal and FALSE if they are not.

To find the value W1&X1 in the entire range, I suggest you use a help column (unless you are willing to write a macro). In the help column of sheet1, you concatenate the values (=W1&X1 - drag down). In the hlep column of sheet2 you do the same. Then you make an additional column to check for matches, by using

`=match(ValueHelpColSheet1,HelpColSheet2,0)`

This formula returns the row number in which the match is found and an error when the corresponding value is not found. You can replace this error with something else using IFERROR if you want to.

Comment: Hi @Lambik,thanks for the reply.

If i will use the above formula, it will only check for the corresponding cell value.I mean it will look for combination of W1&X1 only in the cell Y1 and Z1 of Sheet2.

Actually, I want the combination of value entered in cell of current sheet should check in entire column of Y and Z of Sheet2.

Here, I am expecting, whatever i will enter in W1&X1, the concatenated value should check in the entire column of Y and Z of Sheet2 irrespective of their cell location.If it exist then allow otherwise throw a warning.